# save file in Blackberry 10 WebWorks html5

Tags: html, blackberry-10, blackberry-webworks

I found this https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/apis/blackberry.io.html example that load a file, but, nothing for save a file in html5 webworks to BB10

Answer (score 2):

We actually have a sample that shows how to do this hosted on GitHub.

https://github.com/blackberry/BB10-WebWorks-Samples/tree/master/canvasToFilesystem

The sample shows how to save imageData from a Canvas element to the filesystem, but the actual file writing portion of the sample could be used for any file type.

https://github.com/blackberry/BB10-WebWorks-Samples/blob/master/canvasToFilesystem/saveCanvas.js#L31-L98

Comment: In Ripple emulator say error: `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'invokeFilePicker' ` at line `blackberry.invoke.card.invokeFilePicker(` ... Already add to config.xml `<feature id="blackberry.invoke" />
        <feature id="blackberry.invoke.card" />
        <feature id="blackberry.io" />
        <feature id="blackberry.ui.toast" />`

Comment: Have you also installed the com.blackberry.io and com.blackberry.invoke plugins?

Comment: No, I've done all normal to install the webworks, nothing more. Where I get these plugins?